# Question on epistemic logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Is there any epistemic modal logic in which the knowledge of a conjunction is **not** implied by the knowledge of its conjuncts, i.e.

$\Box A\wedge\Box B\not\Rightarrow\Box(A\wedge B)?$

Comment: I don't know if any such logic was studied (very probably yes), but if yes, it might be helpful to be aware that such logic would be a non-normal modal logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity theoretical aspect of some such logics is investigated in:

- Vardi: [The Complexity of Epistemic Reasoning](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~vardi/papers/lics89.pdf.gz) (1989)

The paper also includes a reference to Vardi's '86 paper which apparently contains more on such logics (I have not read that one, though).